# Ionic 3 with Google Maps: Map not shown

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, cordova, ionic3

I'm trying to get a google maps map using Ionic 3 following a tutorial, but it doesn't work. I cannot see the map but just a blank page, and it is strange, mybe it is a Cordova problem. I did these steps to show the map:

First of all I obtained the Google Api Key.

I adding the following rows into my src/index.html file:

```html
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key={MY API KEY}"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Ionic App</title>
  
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB5yUt2p89SDb8x4rHX23EDGNGyKpgRzyU"></script>
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>

  <base href="/" />

  <meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/icon/favicon.png" />

  <!-- add to homescreen for ios -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

thus, I modified src/app/home/home.page.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Ionic App</title>
  
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB5yUt2p89SDb8x4rHX23EDGNGyKpgRzyU"></script>
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>

  <base href="/" />

  <meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/icon/favicon.png" />

  <!-- add to homescreen for ios -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

and home.page.ts:

```js
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';

declare var google;

@Component({
  selector: 'home-page',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  @ViewChild('map') mapElement: ElementRef;
  map: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

  ionViewDidLoad(){
    this.loadMap();
  }

  loadMap(){

    let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.9290, 138.6010);

    let mapOptions = {
      center: latLng,
      zoom: 15,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);

  }
}
```

Finally, I modified home.page.scss with the following code:

```css
.ios, .md {

    home-page {

      .scroll {
        height: 100%
      }

      #map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }

    }

}
```

with the scss above I should be able to see the map, but instead of this, after 'ionic serve' I have able to see only a blank page:

[image]

Maybe the problem is 'cordova.js', that is present in \platforms\android\platform_www but I don't know actually. The ms Edge console show me that:

> SEC7112: Script from http://localhost:8100/cordova.js was blocked due to MIME type mismatch.
>
> Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
>    Native: tried calling StatusBar.styleDefault, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator
>    Native: tried calling SplashScreen.hide, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator

Edge is the default browser for Ionic Serve, thus, copying and pasting url from Edge to Chrome, I read the following log in console:

> 2cordova.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>
> Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
>
> common.js:290 Native: tried calling StatusBar.styleDefault, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator
>
> common.js:290 Native: tried calling SplashScreen.hide, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator

I need just to see the map, but I do not know Why it doesn't work: according to the .ts file, the maps should appear, but don't.

Comment: You are attempting to display a native Google maps object in a browser.
The map will only show if you run this on an actual device or an emulator (the message above actually says that). 
In the latest version of Ionic (and Google maps) you CAN run it and display the map with ionic serve. However, you need to create the map slightly different, something like this: this.map = GoogleMaps.create(element, options);

Comment: Thank you, but I just tried it from a tutorial. Can you  raccomend a good tutorial for Google Maps using Ionic? However, now I'm trying it using my device, if it will works I will vote your answer

Comment: Hello. It doesn't work also using the smartphone. Blank page

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding `type="text/javascript"`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key={MY API KEY}"></script>
```